# SSRS 2005 - No one has Content Manager rights in the Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, windows, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have the report server installed in the Domain Controller. In the report server, I removed all the roles assigned for BUILTIN\Users (except Browse), and left all the roles (including Content Manager) for BUILTIN\Administrators.

Now when I log in as the Domain Administrator, I cannot access the Security Settings page! I do not get the "Properties" tab in the Report Manager home page.

Since, the server I have installed the SSRS is our domain controller, it doesn't have any BUILTIN groups. However, the Domain Administrator is in the Domain\Administrators group and I was under the impression that will act as the BUILTIN\Administrators group in this case. But I was wrong.

Now since we cannot login as BUILTIN\Administrator, nobody has full access to the Report Manager.

I tried entering entries for ReportServer database PolicyUserRole table, so that I can assign content manager role to the BUILTIN\Users group. Although I added the entries successfully, the Report Manager still shows nothing when I login as a user to the website!

I need to do one of two things, Either

1. some how login as BUILTIN\Administrator to the Report Manager. - But cannot do this coz the Domain Controller doesn't have this group. Domain\Administrators group doesn't seem to be working

or

2.Somehow give ContentManager permission back to the BUILTIN\Users group. But I cannot do this using the ReportManager website OR the SQL Management Studio, as they do not recognize that my domain\Administrator has permission.

Comment: Check that your domain administrator is also a local administrator of the box running SSRS (Local Admins Group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find anything :(... I ended up re-installing the reporting services.

Answer (score 2):

What nonnb said:

- SSRS will allow any "local" administrators to the computer SSRS is running on to do administrative stuff.

You should be able to go to the domain controller, check local users and groups, add in your domain user as a local administrator to the computer. As far as i can remember, even the domain controller also has some local stuff. If not, it could be a discussion on if it is smart or recommended to install SSRS on a domain controller, but that is out of scope for this  question :)

Comment: Thanks cairnz... We have a Windows 2003 Server as the domain controller (which also contains the report server). I tried what you have mentioned. I added my domain user account to the Administrators group. Still no luck!

I actually confirmed that the BUILTIN\Administrators group has the content management right using the mechanism in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600480/ssrs-determine-report-permissions-via-reportserver-database-tables