# ReportServer database - Users have access to which reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportserver

Is there a way, without having to trawl through each report and see which users have access to them? Is it possible to query the ReportServer database to get a list of reports and which users have access to the report?

Or even if I have the user is there a way of knowing all the reports that a specific user has access to?

I have a list of users that I need to look into through the Users table with the ReportServer, can these users be joined to another table in the database to return what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600480/ssrs-determine-report-permissions-via-reportserver-database-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this script below and added a WHERE clause for specific users and could see who has access to what reports etc. Worked nicely :)

```
select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
   inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
   inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
   inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
   inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
order by C.UserName
```

This is the source link - [SSRS - Determine report permissions via ReportServer database tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600480/ssrs-determine-report-permissions-via-reportserver-database-tables)